# php file says Notice: Undefined index: but AJAX POST is successfull. What am i doing wrong?

Tags: jquery, ajax, apache, post, xampp

I know this has been asked 1000 times, but for the past 3 hours I am looking on the internet for solutions but can't find any. 
So I have a button which is generated n times and has a defined class. When I click the button, the function starts and gets the value of the input field. I have put console.log on success and it works, but when I go to the PHP file it says `Notice: Undefined index: pos`.

HERE IS THE JS CODE:

SCRIPT:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.ok').click(function(){
        var pos = $(this).parent().find('.inID').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'cart.php',
            data: {pos : pos},
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(pos);
            }
        }); 

    });
});
```

HTML:

```html
<form method="post" name="addtocart">      
    <input type="hidden" name="cenaHid" class="inID" value="<?php echo $vrstica["cena"];?>">
    <label for="quantity">št.kos:</label>
    <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="1" min="1" max="10">
    <input type="button" value="V kosarico" class="btn ok">    
</form>
```

PHP:

```php
<?php }
$neki = $_POST['pos'];
echo $neki;
```

I am new to Ajax and PHP and I have tried a lot of things to find the solution but I failed.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214787/discussion-on-question-by-blaz-pirc-php-file-says-notice-undefined-index-but-a).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a page which will receive data from your index page and store it inside session.Use ajax request if you do not want page to refresh.You can redirect to your cart.php after ajax success.

**addToCart.php**

```
<?php

// Start the session
session_start();

// Set session variables
$_SESSION["pos"] = $_POST['pos'];
echo 'ok';
?>
```

**cart.php**

```
<?php
//YOUR CODE
$neki = isset($_SESSION["pos"]) ? $_SESSION["pos"] : 'empty'; //Check session data assign to variable if exist otherwise empty will be assigned as a value.

echo $neki;
?>
```

Comment: THANKS! I wasted 10hours of my life for this! Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome @blazpric